# Loop through all rows of a single column in php

Tags: php

I've got a while loop retrieving the information from this statement

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT images.*, users.profile_image, comments.* FROM 
images LEFT JOIN users ON images.user_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN comments ON 
comments.user_id = users.user_id AND images.id = comments.image_id WHERE 
images.id = :id");
```

No problems here, but I need to loop the comments again, otherwise the first loop, loops again because there are two rows in the comments table. This displays everything again but with row 2 of the comments. How can I make it only loop the comments. The first loop will only ever retrieve one result since it is always a unique id.

```
try {
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
 $comment = $row['comment'];
 $title = $row['title'];
 $image = $row['image'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 $category = $row['category'];
 $description = $row['description'];
 $comments = array($row['comment']);
}
?>
<h1><?php echo"$title"; ?></h1>
  <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height:100%; margin-left: auto; margin-
right: auto; display:block;" src="<?php echo "$image" ?>"/>
         <?php
          echo "<h2><span class='by'>By </span><a 
href='users.php/$username.html'>$username </a></h2>";
        echo "<h2><span class='by'>In the </span><a href='browse.php?
category=space'>$category </a><span class='by'>category</span></h2>";
        echo "<h2><span class='by'>About this image:</span></h2> 
$description";
?>
<?php 
    echo "<h2><span class='by'>Comments</span></h2> $comments";

?>
<?php    }

else {
if(!isset($row['id'])){
echo "empty";
}
}
?>
```

Thanks!

**Update**

```
while ($crow = $cstmt->fetch())
    {
        if($crow == false){
            echo "nothing here";
        }
        else {
        $comment = $crow['comment'];
        echo "$comment"; ?><br /><br /><?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can run a new sql to fetch the comments in the post loop. Remove the join of posts with comment,

Comment: You should try Laravel and Eloquent, it has great support for relations in tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to need to split this up into a seperate query or use some logic to establish if it is a new Image or not

EG if split :

```
<?php

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT images.*, users.profile_image FROM 
images LEFT JOIN users ON images.user_id = users.user_id WHERE 
images.id = :id");


try {
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
 $comment = $row['comment'];
 $title = $row['title'];
 $image = $row['image'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 $category = $row['category'];
 $description = $row['description'];
//  $comments = array($row['comment']);
}
?>
<h1><?php echo"$title"; ?></h1>
  <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height:100%; margin-left: auto; margin-
right: auto; display:block;" src="<?php echo "$image" ?>"/>
         <?php
          echo "<h2><span class='by'>By </span><a 
href='users.php/$username.html'>$username </a></h2>";
        echo "<h2><span class='by'>In the </span><a href='browse.php?
category=space'>$category </a><span class='by'>category</span></h2>";
        echo "<h2><span class='by'>About this image:</span></h2> 
$description";
?>
<?php 

//  THIS QUERY WON'T WORK , IT IS FOR CONCEPT ONLY
        $CommentsStmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id = :user_id AND comments.image_id = :image_id");
        $CommentsStmt->bindParam(':user_id', $row['user_id'] , ':user_id' , $row['image_id']);
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $CommentsStmt->execute();
        $CommentsStmt->commit();
        // add a check if it is blank
        echo "<h2><span class='by'>Comments</span></h2> ";
        while ($CommentsRow = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo $CommentsRow['comment'],'<br /><br />';
        }


?>
<?php    }

else {
if(!isset($row['id'])){
echo "empty";
}
}
?>
```

a sample for the non-split version

```
/************
****
******** only output the image details if this is a new image :
****
************/
// NOT SURE WHERE TH IMAGE ID IS COMING FROM SO SUSTITUTE IT HERE:
$current_image_id = $id;
if($previousImageId !== $current_image_id){
?>
            <h1><?php echo"$title"; ?></h1>
            <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height:100%; margin-left: auto; margin-
            right: auto; display:block;" src="<?php echo "$image" ?>"/>
                    <?php
                    echo "<h2><span class='by'>By </span><a 
            href='users.php/$username.html'>$username </a></h2>";
                    echo "<h2><span class='by'>In the </span><a href='browse.php?
            category=space'>$category </a><span class='by'>category</span></h2>";
                    echo "<h2><span class='by'>About this image:</span></h2> 
            $description";
}
/************
****
******** END --- only output the image details if this is a new image :
****
************/
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I feel like splitting would be best for my scenario. Any explanation as to why that query won't work?

Comment: It might well work, I just don't have your database for testing, so unable to tell you for sure if it will. At a glance it just might.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? Check update question